# Some doubts related to the backend users in Typo3 6.1.1

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am pretty new in Typo3 (I came from Joomla and WordPress) and reading the documentation I have some doubts related to the user manage the user in this CMS:

I am using Typo3 6.1.1 and reading here it seems to me that the user managment is quite different (maybe the documentation is related to an old version of the CMS?): http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/EditAndCreatePagesAndContent/CreateUsersGroups/Index.html

In particular I am not understanding if in the 6.1.1 the backend user can ben divided in groups or if they simply are backend user because if I go into: **ADMIN TOOLS ---> Backend User** I can see the backend user but not the groups, why?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Could you update your title to make it more descriptive?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in mentioned doc, BE users can be divided by groups and easiest way for creating BE groups and next BE users is using `WEB > List` module.

Just using workflow showed at screen of [this section](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/EditAndCreatePagesAndContent/CreateUsersGroups/Index.html#backend-users) you need to create records of both types (blue arrows) on the highest page (with id 0 - on screenshot it's called `New TYPO3 site`)

I'm not quite sure about the reason, but `Backend User` module doesn't allow to manage BE groups directly, however there's a tip (which is general for whole TYPO3) - you can create a BE group *ad hoc* - during the process of creating BE user by using additional icons in the form, take a look to screenshot below,  the yellow pencil and black plus allows you to edit/create related records without canceling current edition.

[image: instant relation's editing with additional icons]

Comment: Two hints about BE groups: (at least in 4.x) it is a common practice to create an additional group just for handling pages' rights, to avoid creating pages as admin and usesrs won't see them (see http://www.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF8&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Ft3n.de%2Fmagazin%2Fbenutzerrechte-rechte-seitenbaum-rechtevergabe-222435%2F4%2F). Also, the naming regarding parent groups are confusing, they are labelled "Sub groups".